# MSSQL: Update a row with dynamic variable data when cell is empty

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, sql-update

I need to update the first three columns of a row that are empty with data from the last valid row that matches a constraint (This constraint is constant in this case it is a specific process name). The number of consecutive rows that have empty data in the first three columns is not constant.

I was thinking something with this logic, I am just not sure how to write this in MSSQL

pseudo code:

```
declare @tmp_pname nvarchar(50);
declare @tmp_datetime datetime;
declare @tmp_pid int;
if ProcessName == "MyProc"
    set @tmp_pname = ProcessName
    set @tmp_datetime = DateTime
    set @tmp_pid = PID
else if ProcessName == ""
    update table 
        set ProcessName = @tmp_pname
        set DateTime = @tmp_datetime
        set PID = @tmp_pid
```

Example data:

```
Id    ProcessName     DateTime     PID     LineData
1     Myproc          tmpstamp     123     uniqueData
2     ''              ''           ''      uniqueData
3     ''              ''           ''      uniqueData
4     myproc          tmpstamp     444     uniqueData
5     ''              ''           ''      uniqueData
```

Expected Result:

```
row 2 and 3 get their processname, datetime, and pid from row 1
row 5 gets its processname, datetime, and pid from row 4
```

Thank you in advanced for your assistance!

Comment: Tables do not have an order. Before you go any further you will need to identify what column(s) constitute "previous" and "next" rows.

Comment: I don't understand the specifics of your question, but you'll probably be able to do what you want with the ROW_NUMBER() OVER() function.

Comment: @SeanLange I added an ID row and the expected result

Comment: Adding another column that is all the same within a group will mildly help. What you really need is something solid to order the rows by. This PID would let you order the groups but the rows within them are still not guaranteed to have the order you want. Maybe you can order by PID, DateTime?

Comment: Which SQL Server version (see `SELECT @@VERSION`) ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean 
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
 Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQL2012+**

You could extend next solution:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    Id          INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ProcessName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT  @MyTable (Id, ProcessName) VALUES (1, 'Myproc')
INSERT  @MyTable (Id, ProcessName) VALUES (2, '')
INSERT  @MyTable (Id, ProcessName) VALUES (3, '')
INSERT  @MyTable (Id, ProcessName) VALUES (4, 'myproc')
INSERT  @MyTable (Id, ProcessName) VALUES (5, '')
INSERT  @MyTable (Id, ProcessName) VALUES (6, 'SProc')
INSERT  @MyTable (Id, ProcessName) VALUES (8, '');

WITH Base
AS (
    SELECT  y.ProcessName, y.HasValue, SUM(y.HasValue) OVER(ORDER BY y.Id) AS GroupId
    FROM (
        SELECT  x.Id, x.ProcessName, CASE WHEN x.ProcessName = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HasValue
        FROM    @MyTable x 
    ) y 
)
UPDATE  [target]
SET     ProcessName = source.ProcessName
FROM    Base [target] INNER JOIN Base source ON [target].GroupId = source.GroupId   
WHERE   [target].HasValue = 0
AND     source.HasValue = 1;

SELECT  *
FROM    @MyTable
```

Note #1: I assume that `Id` values are uniques and mandatory.

Note #2: I assume that `ProcessName` column is mandatory (`NOT NULL`).

Note #3: The `(...) y` derived table will split the source data-set (`@MyTable`) into subgroups identified by `GroupId` thus (1) every non-empty string value from `ProcessName` column starts a new `GroupId` and (2) to compute the `GroupId` values it uses the ascending order of values from `Id` column.

Example:

```
ProcessName HasValue    GroupId     Id
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Myproc      1           1           1
            0           1           2
            0           1           3
myproc      1           2           4
            0           2           5
SProc       1           3           6
            0           3           8
```